# Unable to establish connection to safari WebDriver extension using Jenkins and Selenium Grid

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, safari, protractor

I am trying to run our protractor tests on Safari from Jenkins using selenium Grid

I followed the instructions:[here](https://itisatechiesworld.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/steps-to-get-selenium-webdriver-running-on-safari-browser/) 
So I got the "Safari Extension" Developer Certificate, The Safari WebDriver Extension (2.48.2).

Here is my configuration:
I run my tests using protractor with Mocha.

My jenkins machine is running on ubuntu and has a selenium grid running on it.
(selenium version of the grid: 2.41.0: I did not manage to find a way to update the jenkins pluggin to use the version 2.48.2)

I did not manage to set up a node in jenkins + I need version 2.48.2 so I thought I would start the node from my job using ssh.

During the test phase, I started the node (java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node -hub http://[ip]:4444/grid/register -port 8989 -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5 -browser browserName=safari,maxInstances=2 &) by hand directly on the MAC. And the tests were going through. If I go in Safari -> preferences I could see the webdriver installed and enabled.

Then I set up my job to start the node with ssh (same user) and I got this error: "Unable to establish connection to safari WebDriver extension". I try to look in the preferences and the Web driver is not installed at all when started with ssh.

Of course when I start Safari by hand and look at the prefernces I see the Web Driver.

I read in forums that as a workaround we should set: `System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");`
but as I am using protractor I don't see where I should set this property. I try to include the code in the OnPrepare with no luck.

Was anybody able to find a way to make it work? Any suggestions?